# Does jQuery Mobile have a (true) combo-box?

Tags: jquery-mobile, combobox

I am searching for a way to create a combo-box in jQuery Mobile, but there seems to be a lot of confusion between a combo-box and a select (drop-down) box.

My definition, which I learned back when dinosaurs were using Windows 3.0, is that a select box allows you to choose from a drop-down list.  A combo-box does this, but adds the ability to type anything at all (a 'combo' of a selection drop-down and a text input).  These days, from my searching, the distinction seems to have been lost, which is making it extremely difficult to track down info about true combo-boxes.

I like jQuery Mobile's over-all simplicity, and I love the auto-search/complete feature that displays matching options as you type which is 90% of what I need, but I want to capture whatever the user enters, whether it is on the list of options or not.  Can I do this without headache / major work / another plug-in?

Comment: jQuery has, not JQM...http://www.devcurry.com/2011/05/jquery-editable-combo-box.html maybe u can customize it...

Comment: Looks promising. I would call this the answer if it weren't just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has combo box, but not JQM...

try this url: [devcurry.com/2011/05/jquery-editable-combo-box.html](http://devcurry.com/2011/05/jquery-editable-combo-box.html) maybe u can customize it...